# как конвертировать int в 16 ричную систему?

Tags: java, ascii

Добрый день нужно на сервер отправлять данные ф формате 16 речной системы ASCII.К примеру `-1` как `FFFFFFFF` соответсвенно `-2` как `FFFFFFFE`

что это за `fff`-ки?как конверитровать `int a =-1` в   `FFFFFFFF`?

Спасибо за внимание

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183240/java-integer-to-byte-array

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Данный вид записи называется [дополнительный код](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4). В Java можно получить такую запись стандартными средствами:

```
Integer.toHexString(1);        // 1
Integer.toHexString(2);        // 2
Integer.toHexString(-1);       // ffffffff
Integer.toHexString(-2);       // fffffffe
```

Если нужно запись положительных чисел дополнить слева нулями до 8 символов, поможет `String.format()`:

```
String.format("%8s", Integer.toHexString(123)).replace(' ', '0') // 0000007b
```

Comment: почему не `String.format("%08x", 123)`?

Comment: Потому что модификаторы форматирования вылетели из головы, а лезть в документацию было лень) Ваш вариант лучше, конечно.

Answer (score 6):

Самый простой способ

```
int a =-1;
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

В java так

```
 String input = ... // my UTF-16 string
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input.length());
 for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
 char ch = input.charAt(i);
 if (ch <= 0xFF) {
    sb.append(ch);
 }
  }

  byte[] ascii = sb.toString().getBytes("ISO-8859-1"); // aka LATIN-1
```

Comment: на вход принимает параетр типо "-1" ?

Comment: Предположим, `input = "-1"`, что получится?

Comment: мне надо конвертировать -1 в ffffffff  а не в байт